# Which tests to make for this little method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I currently have the following method:

```
public void SetNewRandomValue() {
   double newValue = numberGenerator.GenerateDouble(
                             genesValuesInterval.MinimumValue,
                             genesValuesInterval.MaximumValue
                             );

   this.value = newValue;
}
```

What should be the guidelines for deciding how many tests (and which tests) to make to this method? I currently have done the following one (only after implementing the method -- that is, not test-first):

```
var interval = new Interval(-10, 10);
var numberGeneratorMock = new Mock<INumberGenerator>(MockBehavior.Strict);
var numberGenerator = numberGeneratorMock.Object;

double expectedValue = 5.0;

numberGeneratorMock.Setup(ng => 
        ng.GenerateDouble(interval.MinimumValue, interval.MaximumValue))
        .Returns(expectedValue);

var gene = new Gene(numberGenerator, 0, new Interval(-10, 10));
gene.SetNewRandomValue();

Assert.AreEqual<double>(expectedValue, gene.Value);
```

that basically just tests one situation. Regression-testingwise I'd say that I can't think of a way of messing up the code, turning it into mal functioning code and still have the test pass, that is, I think the method looks decently covered.

What are your opinions on this? How would you handle this little method?

Thanks

Comment: I'm apprehensive to post this as a solution, as I'm by no means a Unit Testing god. However, If you've sufficiently tested your number generator, and your min/max retrieval from genesValues, then I would stop with that. if you know those work, all you'd be testing is that this.value gets set.

Comment: What's the second parameter in the `Gene` constructor?

Answer (score 2):

I would examine the code coverage with whatever testing tool you use, if a code coverage is available for your testing framework.

I personally like to work with either `Microsoft Testing Tool` or `NUnit Testing Framework`. I can then right-click my tests project and `Test with NCover` (while using NUnit), which will run the tests and tell me the percentage of code covered for each of my objects and tests.

I say that when you'll be done checking the code coverage which would result of at least a 98% code coverage, your code is likely to be well tested.

Comment: I would disagree with this. The code coverage is very, very misleading. You can mock all your calls and then Assert.IsTrue(1 == 1) and you'll have 100% code coverage with no actual testing. I will agree with you that it's a good sanity check in making sure you've hit all the bases, but it won't guarantee you hit them well :)

Comment: Personally, I would not try to hit each piece of code and make a fake assertion such as `Assert.IsTrue(1 == 1)`, which would be the same as `Assert.Pass()`, in my opinion. This doesn't really make sense. When I'm using code coverage, I look at what has not yet been hit by the tests, and elaborate the best test I can in order to make sure I have tested it good. Anyway, with your argument, I can't do better than agree with you. I had not looked at it this way. =)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend taking a look at [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) - it can really help generate the kind of unit tests you're looking for (i.e. figure out the different potential paths and results given a method and return value).

Answer (score 1):

That test looks fine. The only thing you can actually assert about `SetNewRandomValue` is that the `Value` member is assigned afterward. You've mocked out the call to `GenerateDouble` and verified that `Value` contains the expected number, so you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

You could definitely make a case for not unit testing this. IMHO, code inspection is a perfectly valid test methodology. You generally don't test things like property setters/getters, I think this method is simple enough to avoid unit testing for the same reason.

That said, if you really do want to test it, here's what I'd do: I'd test it with a couple values, not just once with 5. (SetNewRandomValue could be implemented as `this.value = 5;`, which should not pass.) I'd test it with a non-integer number, to confirm there's not a oddball cast to integer in there.

You could test that it's calling GenerateDouble with the proper parameters, though that's really testing an implementation detail. (SetNewRandomValue could be implemented as `numberGenerator.GenerateDouble(0, interval.max - interval.min) + interval.min;`, and that shouldn't fail the test.) You could use a real random number generator, and do SetNewRandomValue a few thousand times, and test that the values are evenly distributed in your expected range.

Answer (score 1):

You could also write a test to document (and verify) the expected behavior of `Gene.SetNewRandomValue` when `NumberGenerator.GenerateDouble` returns a value outside the specified interval.

Answer (score 1):

The method is doing three things:
 Calling `numberGenerator.GenerateDouble` with `genesValuesInterval.MinimumValue` as the first parameter,
  and with `genesValuesInterval.MaximumValue` as the second parameter,
  and setting `this.value` to the result of that call.

Your test tests the third of these things, but not the first two. You could write two more tests that check the mock is called with the correct first and second parameters.

Edit (responding to comments below):
If the intended behaviour of this method is to set `this.value` to a random double within a previously specified range, then the above three tests are useful (assuming `genesValuesInterval` min and max are the previously specified range and that you have tests in place to assert that numberGenerator.GenerateDouble(min, max) returns a double within the specified range.

If the intended behaviour of this method is just to set `this.value` to a random double within (Double.MinValue, Double.MaxValue), then the first two tests are unnecessary as this is just an implementation detail.

If the inted

Comment: The first two are implementation details.

Comment: @Jason: Unit tests are supposed to test the implementation details of a method.

Comment: You can't assume that -10 and 10 are the proper parameters. They could pass 0 & 20, and then subtract 10 from the resulting double.

Comment: @Jackson Pope: No they are not Not NOT! They are suppose to test the _behavior_ of a method. The whole point is that I can change the implementation details but as long as I don't change the behavior then I will still have a unit test that passes. If my unit tests are heavily dependent on implementation details then I have very brittle tests that will fail every time I refactor even if I'm not changing the semantics. Put another way, unit tests are clients of code just as anyone else is a client of code. Implementation details are to be hidden from clients. Clients only care about behavior.

Comment: @Jackson Pope: A unit test should not care if `int Add(int m, int n)` is implemented as `Adder adder = new Adder(); int result = adder.Add(m, n); return result;` or if it is implemented as `return m + n;`. Those are implementation details that clients of code should not care about. They only care about the behavior that the method returned a number that is equal to `m + n`.

Comment: @Jason, yeah sorry it was late and I was clearly tired. I'm about to amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer how to test it, you should be able to describe what is the desired behavior.

Looking at your code, I assume that "Gene.SetNewRandomValue" is supposed to set `self.Value` to a number which falls within the Interval passed to the constructor.

I'm not super familiar with the `Mock` class, so I may be off base, but it appears that you are not testing that.   What if your implementation had this typo?

```
double newValue = numberGenerator.GenerateDouble( 
                         genesValuesInterval.MinimumValue, 
                         genesValuesInterval.MinimumValue 
                         );
```

Wouldn't your test still pass?